# Receiver unregisterProblem

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I am having the following problem in my app.
In on resume of my activity I register a broadcast receiver using this:

```
NetworkStateReceivernetworkStateReceiver = new NetworkStateReceiver(UIWrapperActivity.this);        
filterConnectivity = new IntentFilter();
filterConnectivity.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
registerReceiver(networkStateReceiver, filterConnectivity);
```

And then in `onPause` I unregister it:

```
unregisterReceiver(networkStateReceiver);
```

In broadcast receiver in the same activity I catch `CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` and show a certain activity (Something like noConnection) switching to this activity does trigger `onPause()` of first activity so receiver is unregistered but than when I try to close the noConnection activity using `finish()` it's just reopened and won't go away.

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong and why is my broadcast receiver not unregistered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found out what I was doing wrong so if someone gets this same error, here is the solution.
I didn't finish the activity when I caught intent broadcast in the receiver so keep an eye out for that because if activity is still alive then it calls it's `onResume()` again and receiver gets re-registered.